# How to integrate AWS CodeBuild with Python pytest-cov code coverage report in buildspec.yaml

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, code-coverage, aws-codebuild, buildspec

I have a Python-based application that consists of:

- Some Python source code that uses the AWS Boto3 SDK to interact with AWS resource
- A Dockerfile that builds upon the AWS `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9` image
- An AWS SAM (Serverless Application Model) template that builds a lambda to execute the Docker image when the lambda is invoked

The first part of my build commands in the `buildspec.yaml` file are intended to execute all unit tests with a code coverage report. This works well.

I was able to integrate the unit test report with AWS CodeBuild using the `reports` section of the buildspec:

```
reports:
  pytest_reports:
    files:
      - junitxml-report.xml
  base-directory: ./pytest_reports
  file-format: JUNITXML
```

This works as expected. I can see that a new "Report group" and the first report was created in CodeBuild after my code pipeline executed. Unfortunately, this only includes the unit test results report.

**QUESTION: How do I integrate my Python code coverage report with CodeBuild via the buildspec.yaml file?**

I have found some information on [this AWS documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/code-coverage-report.html), but the list of code coverage report formats did not include anything that I can generate from a Python code coverage run. I am still somewhat new to Python development, so I was hoping an expert may have already solved this.

For reference, here is my complete buildspec.yaml file (with some sensitive values scrubbed):

```
version: 0.2

env:

  variables:
    # Elastic Container Registry (ECR) hosts
    MAIN_REPO: 999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    DR_REPO: 999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com


phases:

  install:
    runtime-versions:
        python: 3.9

  build:
    on-failure: ABORT
    commands:
      # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # PART 1 - EXECUTE UNIT TESTS AND CODE COVERAGE ON THE PYTHON SOURCE CODE
      # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # install/upgrade build-related modules that CodeBuild will use
      - python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
      - python3 -m pip install --upgrade pytest
      - python3 -m pip install --upgrade pytest-mock
      - python3 -m pip install --upgrade pytest-cov
      # do local user 'install' of source code, then run pytest (company-private Pypi repo must be explicitly included)
      - pip install --extra-index-url https://artifactory.my-company-domain.com/artifactory/api/pypi/private-pypi/simple -e ./the_python_code
      - python3 -m pytest --junitxml=./pytest_reports/junitxml-report.xml --cov-fail-under=69 --cov-report xml:pytest_reports/cov.xml --cov-report html:pytest_reports/cov_html --cov-report term-missing --cov=./the_python_code/src/ ./the_python_code
      # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # PART 2 - BUILD THE DOCKER IMAGE AND PUBLISH TO ECR
      # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # REFERENCE: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html
      # Pre-authenticate access to Docker Hub and Elastic Container Registry for image pulls and pushes
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
      - docker image build -t 999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-docker-image-tag-name .
      - docker push 999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-docker-image-tag-name
      # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # PART 3 - BUILD THE SAM PROJECT
      # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      - printenv
      - echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
      - 'echo "ARTIFACTS_BUCKET_NAME : $ARTIFACTS_BUCKET_NAME"'
      - 'echo "ARTIFACTS_BUCKET_PATH : $ARTIFACTS_BUCKET_PATH"'
      - 'echo "CODEBUILD_KMS_KEY_ID  : $CODEBUILD_KMS_KEY_ID"'
      - echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
      - MAIN_TEMPLATE="main-template.yaml"
      - sam build --debug
      - |
        sam package \
          --template-file .aws-sam/build/template.yaml \
          --output-template-file "${MAIN_TEMPLATE}" \
          --image-repository  "999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-docker-image-tag-name" \
          --s3-bucket "${ARTIFACTS_BUCKET_NAME}" \
          --s3-prefix "${ARTIFACTS_BUCKET_PATH}" \
          --kms-key-id "${CODEBUILD_KMS_KEY_ID}" \
          --force-upload

reports:
  pytest_reports:
    files:
      - junitxml-report.xml
    base-directory: ./pytest_reports
    file-format: JUNITXML

artifacts:
  files:
    - main-template.yaml
    - parameters/*.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional section under 'reports', so yours would look like:

```
reports:
  pytest_reports:
    files:
      - junitxml-report.xml
    base-directory: ./pytest_reports
    file-format: JUNITXML
  coverage_tests:
    files:
      - coverage.xml
    file-format: COBERTURAXML
```

Thanks to [How to get report for test coverage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70571744/how-to-get-report-for-test-coverage)